# Angular - Block navigation from component (without route guard)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm trying to prevent navigation until the user confirms they will lose their changes, but I don't think I can use a route guard in my scenario.

Here is the check for changes:

```js
public get hasChanged(): boolean {
    return this.changeManager.hasChanged({
        propA: this.propACtrl.value,
        propB: this.propBCtrl.value,
        // ETC, lots of other checks
    });
}
```

```js
class ChangeManager {
    // bunch of properties containing original values

    public hasChanged(args: ChangeManagerArguments): boolean {
        return this.propA !== args.propA || this.propB !== args.propB // etc...
    }
}
```

Therefore, I don't think I can use a service, since this check is done at a specific timing, the service will not have that information (since it doesn't have access to all those properties it needs to check).

For the moment, I can handle the scenario where the user uses the browser features to leave the page (back button, home button, closing tab etc...) by doing this:

```js
@HostListener("window:beforeunload")
public unloadHandler(): boolean {
    if (this.hasChanged) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I have something similar if the user navigates via a routerLink? Is there a way to achieve this with a route guard?

Comment: You can move `routerLink` on confirmation button of dialog, and only have functionality to open confirmation dialog instead of current `routerLink`

Comment: I have a sidenav on the side that holds all the navigations, which is in another component, multiple level above. Worst case I can query the DOM with ViewContent but that's nasty. Thx for the idea though

Comment: *Is there a way to achieve this with a route guard?* yes, implement `canDeactivate` callback.

Comment: And how do I access my component properties to handle the check?

Comment: pass it via common service (or you can even inject your callback directly in the component, but I didnt try that)

Comment: That would mean updating those values every time something changes in the screen which is way too big (the screen contains a complex grid system where the user can do a lot of different changes).

Comment: But you have a routine that determines if something was changed or not anyway already haven you? `ChangeManager#hasChange`?

Comment: As you can see in the answer, I guessed it right and you can inject component into the guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First need to create PendingChangesGuard as below:

```
export interface ComponentCanDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}

@Injectable()
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate,
            route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
            state: RouterStateSnapshot,
            nextState: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
       
             
    // if there are no pending changes, just allow deactivation; else confirm first
     return component.canDeactivate() ?
       true :
       confirm('WARNING: You have unsaved changes. Press Cancel to go back and save these changes, or OK to lose these changes.');
  }
}
```

Routing Path add Guard

```
{ path: 'path...', component: ComponentName, canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard] },
```

//Write below code in component where you want to check the change done or not?

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // insert logic to check if there are pending changes here;
    // returning true will navigate without confirmation
    // returning false will show a confirm dialog before navigating away
    if(this.list.length>0){   // Check whatever condition you have 
       return false;
    }
     else{
       return true;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So you inject component into the guard?